# Info to update Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-rc

I am using Selenium IDE 2.9.1 at the moment and beginner in Selenium. I invoke the test suite from a .bat file which contains following command:

java -jar C:\Apps\SeleniumTest\selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://testurl" "C:\Apps\SeleniumTest\SeleniumSuite.html" "C:\Apps\SeleniumTest\SeleniumTestResult.html"

The test suite executes successfully but in TestResult file that is generated following is logged as info:

info: Selenium 1.0 (Core, RC, etc) is no longer under active development. Please update to WebDriver ASAP

I am not planning to use WebDriver, RC. My plan is to stick to Selenium IDE only for basic automation test scripts. Can somebody please tell me what action steps should I take now? I read one similar post but could not find a concrete solution.

Comment: You don't need to do anything if you current requirement is satisfied(many tool are no longer under maintenance but still have many user) and that project will not update using the new technology. But I suggest you to learn the new tool in next project since they are more powerfully when dealing with the new internet stuff/technology.

Comment: @Kit - Thanks! Which tool do you suggest? I am in the initial phase only so i can still switch to another tool if it's better.

Comment: Sah or  Watir-WebDriver or Selenium WebDriver combining with other testing framework, cucumber , etc.